# Booting Windows XP from original CD requires SP2 disc

Tags: windows-xp, boot, service-pack

I need to repair a Windows XP installation, but booting from the original CD requires a Service Pack 2 CD at the very beginning, which I don't have since I got SP2 through Windows Update.

How do I get a Windows XP CD with SP2? Simply burning the update file (a single .exe you can download from Microsoft) to a CD does not sound promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slipstream Service Pack 2. In short that means integrating the service pack into your original Windows setup files and burning the updated ISO to a CD.

Here are some links for you to get started. Both are very detailed and with pictures.

- [Slipstreaming Windows XP using basic, freely available tools](http://www.derangedcoder.net/programming/windows/slipstreamingWindowsXP.html) (using ImgBurn)
- [Slipstreaming Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2)](http://winsupersite.com/article/product-review/slipstreaming-windows-xp-with-service-pack-2-sp2) (using Nero or Roxio)

Note: The procedure is the same in both cases, only the burning software used differs.

**Main steps**:

1. Copy the contents of your XP CD to the hard drive
2. Get the XP SP2 installer and extract it
3. Combine XP with SP2 (refer to the guides above for details)
4. Extract a file needed to make the disc bootable, and create the ISO file
5. Burn the ISO file to a CD

Comment: I used n-lite for slipstreaming in the end. Thank you.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas Ah forgot to mention nLite. Thats of course way easier since its designed exactly for these concerns.